# Uable to access element in dropdown using xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath

I have a web page with a time zone drop-down where I want to access the options
[image]

The HTML is as follows:

```
            <li>
              <div id="ember2503" class="artdeco-dropdown__item artdeco-dropdown__item--is-dropdown ember-view" tabindex="0"><!---->
                (UTC-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa
              </div>
            </li>
```

I want to select the option using the text attribute.
Using text attribute will allow me to access the option by just having a variable 'capital's name'.

I tried to access this with text() attribute but it is not visible.
Here is the XPath:

```
//div[contains(text(),'Midway')]
```

This XPath is not working. Is there any way to access this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one instead

```
//div[contains(.,'Midway')]
```

Comment: wow! you just replied within a minute!
thanks.
this worked
//li//div[contains(.,'Midway')]

Comment: is there any explanation why regular one does not work?
//div[contains(text(),'Midway')]

Comment: @faaizhashmi `contains(text(),'Midway')` means that you want to check whether **first text child** of `div` contains `"Midway"`. While it looks like there is only one text child it's not really so... The first text node is just an empty string. That's why your XPath does not work. `contains(.,'Midway')` predicate means that you want to check whether **string representation** of `div` contains `"Midway"`

Comment: So you mean in our example the first child is a comment i.e <!---->

Comment: @faaizhashmi I'm not sure. But you can check. You can do `//div/text()` to get all text children list or `count(//div/text())` to get number of text children...